# How to get started with Server Side - Java - Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, server-side

I'm very new to server side programming, and I want to develop something by using java and Spring framework. I'm working in Android technology for the last two years and I'm very much familiar with Java and Eclipse IDE.

Can anyone provide me links to some useful tutorials and examples?
Which IDE will be more suitable for me? Eclipse or Netbeans?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Eclipse is more suitable, Because you already know about Eclipse(Eclipse is used for android projects).

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html

http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Answer (score 4):

It's a very vague question but I'll give you my opinion:

- [Learn Java EE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) - this includes:
- JSP/JSF
- Servlets
- Web
- EJB 3

Build an application using these technologies and only after you familiarize yourself with it, only then start using spring. Spring is using a lot of theses technologies behind the scenes and it is important to understand what is going on

Regarding eclipse vs netbeans - I'm a huge fan of eclipse and i think it is a great tool however netbeans has better integration with Glassfish (sun/oracle application server) and better GUI tools. so it is really a matter of taste.

As for web/application servers:

1. [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) is a great server to start with, but since it is a web server it does not support EJB.
2. For using EJB you'll need an application server like [Jboss](http://www.jboss.org/as7) or [glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/).

I'd start with tomcat and then move to glassfish.

Answer (score 2):

What IDEs are you used to? I recommend that you use [STS - Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.org/sts), which is an Eclipse based IDE maintained by SpringSource. Alternatively, the [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) also provide good support for Spring projects.